# Edit/Updating user fields in current session in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So far I have implemented a simple user with authentication ( user controller and session controller) and I want to go to a MyAccount page using a users#edit route and update, say the email adress of the current user. The problem is that the update function is updating the current view with the email I want to change, but not the database, so when I hit refresh the @user.email object would return to its initial value. Thank you!

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
    redirect_to log_in_path, :notice => "Signed up!"
   else
    render "new"
   end
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
     end
  end
 end

  private
  def set_user
      @user = current_user
  end

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

I have also added the sessions controller I have created.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in"
    else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out"
  end
end
```

My routes are as follows:

```
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  #get "my_account" => "users#show", :as => "my_account"
  get "my_account" => "users#edit", :as => "my_account"

  get "main/index"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
```

Finally, my Application controller and aplication.html:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end   
end
```

In application.html is where I used the current_user method:

```
<div id="user_nav">
<% if current_user %>
    Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>
    <%= link_to "Log out", log_out_path %>
    <%= link_to "My Account", my_account_path %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %> 
    <%= link_to "Log in", log_in_path %> 
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: In your users controller, try replacing if @user.update(:current_user) with if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

Comment: I tried it as well, still no effect on the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using

```
if @user.update(:current_user)
```

It should be something like:

```
if @user.update(user_params)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I did that as it makes more sense but the error still remains.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is simple and maybe you already corrected this but...

instead of

```
if @user.update(user_paramas)
```

try

```
if @user.update(user_params)
```

Comment: Ups. I typed it wrong here but in the code it was alright. I switched to using Devise auth instead and it works like a charm. hanks anyway